# Checking the Group Axioms

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose we have a triple $(G,*, 1_G)$. If I want to check that this triple is a group, is it always necessary to check the group axioms? For instance, if I could find some set $X$ such that $G$ is an $X$-set, i.e., $X$ acts on $G$, would this imply that $G$ is a group?

In other words, is there a quick way to check that a triple is a group without having to go through and check the axioms?

Comment: What does it mean for a set to act on another set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many shortcuts that people use.

For example, function composition is always associative, making it very easy to prove that the set of self-bijections of a set is a group under the operation of composition; this gives sort of an answer to your question about "actions".

For another example, if you already have a group in your hands, to prove a subset is a subgroup all you have to do is prove that if $a,b$ are in the subset then $ab^{-1}$ is also.

For another example, if you already have a homomorphism between two groups $f : G \to H$, then the kernel of $f$ and the image of $f$ are easily proved to be subgroups of $G$ and $H$, respectively.